# Are there limitations in building a multiple-page site that functions like a single page site?

Tags: ajax, web-applications, seo, single-page-application

I was determined to construct a new project as a single-page site but a fellow developer planted a seed of doubt when considering SEO. I've read plenty of articles on both sides and understand the differences and considerations.

But couldn't a site be constructed with multiple pages but function as a single page site once the user initially lands on a given page?

It seems so simple, I'm wondering if I'm overlooking things.

Answer (score 0):

The key would be to not duplicate content across your different pages and get slapped with a dup content penalty from a search engine algo. To accomplish what you are asking I think you would have to AJAX in your content from each separate page and then have it displayed on your single, interactive page.